# Using email-address instead of username causes "Login failed" on nextcloud

Tags: android, active-directory, ldap, nextcloud

We are facing some random issue with login using nextcloud. It is working for some user and not for the others.
We are trying to login using email id of AD user.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcom to SO, and you need to read about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question seem about related with your service, not a programmatically problem.

Answer (score 0):

The email address (`mail` attribute) cannot be used for login. However, the `userPrincipalName` attribute can be used to login, and can (but doesn't have to) match the `mail` attribute.

For your problem users, make sure the `userPrincipalName` matches their email address.